WPF App as desktop, not on taskbar and no alt+tab. (like Rainmeter)
I want my WPF app to "Replace" the windows background, like Rainmeter has widgets on the desktop. I don't want to be able to alt+tab to it or see it on the task bar. Is this possible?
I don't want to completely replace the background. When trying to search I only found NO answers and privacy settings and stuff for background apps.
EDIT: Just to clarify something, I want it to still show when I press Windows + D (hide all apps), so it will always shown unless in a different app.
